# Gcm push notification not working after changing package name?

Tags: android, push-notification

my app push notification not recieves after i change package name using Android tools>Rename application package

Comment: Atleast,show some code.

Comment: its working before i change package name

Comment: You might have not modified your android manifest file.

Comment: i used Android tools>Rename application this property of eclipse

Comment: Can you please post your manifest file

Answer (score 2):

go to Google Developers Console, then APIs & auth, then Credentials. You have there OAuth key for your old package name, create new or change old one